# It is possible to extract my current toolchain?

Tags: gcc, glibc, toolchain, gnu-toolchain

Hi I want to migrate to a modern operating system, but I want to conserve my current (an older) GCC and GLIBC version to be able to obtain the same binary files. I know that it is possible to download and use other toolchains for this, but I can't found my exact combination of GCC and GLIBC versions, so I want to build my toolchain with my desired combination. It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible?

Yes: building a cross-compiler that will contain older GCC and target older GLIBC is possible.

However, it is non-trivial. It is also far from guaranteed to reproduce your existing builds.

A better approach might be to set up a `chroot`ed environment, or a VM, containing your *current* toolchain and GLIBC.